# Objective C iOS - objc_object::sidetable_retain/release chewing up CPU time in my loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on a **Spritekit** Tower Defence game. **ARC** is enabled. (And I intend to run this code in the background, though presently it's just running on the main thread.)

In my update loop (which is running up to 60 times a second) I call a method called `getTargetsForTowers`. After profiling this method, I've found two items in the list that are chewing up my CPU time: `objc_object::sidetable_retain/release`, and I'm trying to find out what they are.

I'd like to understand more about what this is and if I can improve performance by reducing them or getting rid of them altogether.

There are 300 enemies and 446 towers in my test scenario. The majority of the CPU time is reported in the tower loop.

```
- (void)getTargetsForTowers {
    NSArray *enemiesCopy = [enemiesOnMap copy];
    for (CCUnit *enemy in enemiesCopy) {
        float edte = enemy.distanceToEnd;
        CGPoint enemyPos = enemy.position;
        [self calculateTravelDistanceForEnemy:enemy];
        if (enemy.actualHealth > 0) {
            NSArray *tiles = [self getTilesForEnemy:enemy];
            for (CCTileInfo *tile in tiles) {
                NSArray *tileTowers = tile.towers;
                for (CCSKTower *tower in tileTowers) {
                    BOOL hasTarget = tower.hasTarget;
                    BOOL passes = !hasTarget;
                    if (!passes) {
                        CCUnit *tg = tower.target;
                        float tdte = tg.distanceToEnd;
                        passes = edte < tdte;
                    }
                    if (passes) {
                        BOOL inRange = [self circle:tower.position withRadius:tower.attackRange collisionWithCircle:enemyPos collisionCircleRadius:1];
                        if (inRange) {
                            tower.hasTarget = YES;
                            tower.target = enemy;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshots from Time Profile (after 60 seconds of running):

[image one http://imageshack.com/a/img22/2258/y18v.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img22/2258/y18v.png)

[image two http://imageshack.com/a/img833/7969/7fy3.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img833/7969/7fy3.png)

(I've been reading about blocks, arc, strong/weak references, etc., so I tried making the variables (such as CCSKTower *tower) __weak, which did get rid of those two items, but that added a whole bunch of new items related to retaining/creating/destroying the weak variables, and I think they consumed more CPU time than before.)

I'd appreciate any input on this. Thanks.

**EDIT**:

There's another method that I would like to improve as well which is:

```
- (NSArray *)getTilesForEnemy:(CCUnit *)enemy {
    NSMutableArray *tiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
    float enemyWidthHalf = enemy.size.width/2;
    float enemyHeightHalf = enemy.size.height/2;
    
    float enemyX = enemy.position.x;
    float enemyY = enemy.position.y;
    
    CGVector topLeft = [self getVectorForPoint:CGPointMake(enemyX-enemyWidthHalf, enemyY+enemyHeightHalf)];
    CGVector topRight = [self getVectorForPoint:CGPointMake(enemyX+enemyWidthHalf, enemyY+enemyHeightHalf)];
    CGVector bottomLeft = [self getVectorForPoint:CGPointMake(enemyX-enemyWidthHalf, enemyY-enemyHeightHalf)];
    CGVector bottomRight = [self getVectorForPoint:CGPointMake(enemyX+enemyWidthHalf, enemyY-enemyHeightHalf)];
    
    CCTileInfo *tile = nil;
    for (float x = topLeft.dx; x < bottomRight.dx+1; x++) {
        for (float y = bottomLeft.dy; y < topRight.dy+1; y++) {
            if (x > -(gameHalfCols+1) && x < gameHalfCols) {
                if (y < gameHalfRows && y > -(gameHalfRows+1)) {
                    int xIndex = (int)(x+gameHalfCols);
                    int yIndex = (int)(y+gameHalfRows);
                    tile = tileGrid[xIndex][yIndex];
                    if (tile != nil) {
                        [tiles addObject:tile];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return tiles;
}
```

I've looked over it repeatedly and there's nothing I really can see. Perhaps there's nothing more that can be done.

Screenshots:

[image: image three]

[image: image four]

Comment: Did you try an `__unsafe_unretained` on `tg`? Just a hunch.

Comment: I just tried that now. This seemed to only shift the percentages in the if statement all to the *tg line, which was 50%.

Here's the screenshot: http://imageshack.com/a/img19/5357/5ph1.png

Comment: @Tommy -- I just realised I didn't add your name in the reply.

Comment: Then I think it's the getter that's now causing the problem — is it automatically generated? If so it's doing a `retain` and an `autorelease` to ensure anything you get is still valid even if the parent object is deallocated.

Comment: @Tommy, Hmm, I see. I assume they're generated automatically, as I haven't done them manually. Is there any easy way for me to stop it from retaining and autoreleasing?

Comment: I'm not sure about a particularly easy way; you basically want to override the things ARC is doing but ARC doesn't have that sort of flexibility since it thinks it is making everything easiest if memory management just works. If you want the interface still to be clean would guess that declaring the property as unsafe_unretained but overriding the getter and also assigning the object to a strong instance variable would cut out the retain/autorelease on getting.

Comment: @Tommy Hmm I see. When you say "overriding the getter", what changes would I make to it? How would it different from the default?

And by "assigning the object to a strong instance variable", do you mean __strong *tg = ... ?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One issue is that you create a new reference to `tower.target`, but only use that reference once.  So simply rewriting that section should improve your performance, e.g.

```
if (!passes) {
    float tdte = tower.target.distanceToEnd;
    passes = edte < tdte;
}
```

---

Based on your comment, it seems that there's no way to avoid a retain/release if you access a property on `tower.target`.  So let's try radical surgery.  Specifically, try adding a `distanceToEnd` property to the tower, to keep track of the `distanceToEnd` for the tower's current target.  The resulting code would look like this.

```
- (void)getTargetsForTowers {

    // initialization to copy 'distanceToEnd' value to each tower that has a target
    for ( CCSKTower *tower in towersOnMap )
        if ( tower.hasTarget )
            tower.distanceToEnd = tower.target.distanceToEnd;

    NSArray *enemiesCopy = [enemiesOnMap copy];
    for (CCUnit *enemy in enemiesCopy) {
        float edte = enemy.distanceToEnd;
        CGPoint enemyPos = enemy.position;
        [self calculateTravelDistanceForEnemy:enemy];
        if (enemy.actualHealth > 0) {
            NSArray *tiles = [self getTilesForEnemy:enemy];
            for (CCTileInfo *tile in tiles) {
                NSArray *tileTowers = tile.towers;
                for (CCSKTower *tower in tileTowers) {
                    if ( !tower.hasTarget || edte < tower.distanceToEnd ) {
                        BOOL inRange = [self circle:tower.position withRadius:tower.attackRange collisionWithCircle:enemyPos collisionCircleRadius:1];
                        if (inRange) {
                            tower.hasTarget = YES;
                            tower.target = enemy;
                            tower.distanceToEnd = edte;   // update 'distanceToEnd' on the tower to match new target
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

My impression is that there's not much to be done about the `getTilesForEnemy` method. Looking at the `Running Time` image for `getTilesForEnemy` it's clear that the load is fairly evenly spread among the various components of the method, with only three items above 10%. The top item `getVectorForPoint` isn't even in the innermost loop. The second item `insertObject` is apparently the result of the `addObject` call in the inner loop, but there's nothing to be done for that call, it's required to generate the final result.

At the next level up (see the `wvry.png` image), you can see that `getTilesForEnemy` is now 15.3% of the total time spent in `getTargetsForTowers`. So even if it were possible to reduce `getVectorForPoint` from 17.3% to 7.3% there would not be a significant reduction in running time.  The savings in `getTilesForEnemy` would be 10%, but because `getTilesForEnemy` is only 15.3% of the time in `getTargetsForTowers`, the overall savings would only be 1.53%.

Conclusion, because the components of `getTilesForEnemy` are balanced and below 20%, and because `getTilesForEnemy` is only 15.3% of the higher level method, no significant savings will be gained by trying to optimize `getTilesForEnemy`.

So once again the only option is radical surgery, and this time I mean a total rewrite of the algorithm.  Such action should only be taken if the app still isn't performing up to spec. You've run into the limitations of ARC and NSArray's.  Both of those technologies are extremely powerful and flexible, and are perfect for high-level development.  However, they both have significant overhead which limits performance. So the question becomes, "How do you write the `getTargetsForTowers` without using ARC and NSArray's?".  The answer is to use arrays of C structs to represent the objects. The resulting top level pseudo code would be something like this

```
copy the enemy information into an array of C structs
copy the tower information into an array of C structs
  (note that the target for a tower is just an 'int', which is the index of an enemy in the enemy array)
for ( each enemy in the enemy array )
{ 
   create an array of C structs for the tiles
   for ( each tile )
      for ( each tower in the tile )
         update the tower target if needed
}
copy the updated tower information back into the NSArray of tower objects
```

Comment: That's how I coded it originally. To try and "spread out" the possible culprit I used more lines of code as in the example. The result was more or less the same.

Here's the screenshot: http://imageshack.com/a/img829/8616/gfpp.png

Comment: @thebro Alright, I gave it another shot, if you're still interested.

Comment: I've tried your edited code, and it seems to have worked well. The performance increase is substantial. These are the new tests:

http://imageshack.com/a/img35/1252/zvo5.png
http://imageshack.com/a/img843/2329/wvry.png

I'd like to ask before I mark your answer as correct, if it's possible to further reduce sidetable_release(bool) and/or objc_msgSend, tower.hasTarget, tower.targetDistanceToEnd, etc.?

Thank you very much for your help, it's much appreciated!

Comment: My understanding is that because `tower` is setup in the `for` loop, there are no penalties for accessing the properties of `tower`, as long as they are non-object types, e.g. float, bool, CGPoint.  There would be a penalty for accessing an object, e.g. the `target` property. I don't see any more easy optimizations in the innermost loop, so I'm glad to hear that you got a performance bump from the previous suggestion.

Comment: I see. What about setting the enemiesCopy array to nil at the end of the method, or setting enemy to nil after I've set tower.target = enemy? Does that do anything useful?

Also when the if statement 'if (!tower.hasTarget || edte <<...)' is evaluated, if !tower.hasTarget returns true, is the second parameter evaluated? I'm wondering if I could save a little performance by only only checking the distances between tower and target if the tower has a target.

Additionally, if I edit my original question, would you take a quick look at my getTilesForEnemy method? It's smaller.

Comment: I'll take a look tomorrow, as it's getting late here.  The one thing I can answer quickly is that an `if` statement that contains a logical or `||`, the second part won't be evaluated if the first part is true.  That's absolutely guaranteed by the C language spec.

Comment: Ah I see. Great. All right, well thank you again. I'll update my post with my other method for you to look at if you get a chance. I'll wait until then to mark your answer as correct. (Otherwise I might not be able to edit it? I'm not sure.)

Comment: @thebro Ok, I've updated the answer once again. Best of luck :-)

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I agree, I don't think there's much I can do with that method either. And I don't want to go to c arrays in the other method because I think that'll complicate things and I don't want that. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

For your second method, this part seems unclear and inefficient:

```
    for (float x = topLeft.dx; x < bottomRight.dx+1; x++) {
        for (float y = bottomLeft.dy; y < topRight.dy+1; y++) {
            if (x > -(gameHalfCols+1) && x < gameHalfCols) {
                if (y < gameHalfRows && y > -(gameHalfRows+1)) {
```

For instance, there's no point in spinning the y loop if your x is out of bounds. You could just do this:

```
    for (float x = topLeft.dx; x < bottomRight.dx+1; x++) {
        if (x > -(gameHalfCols+1) && x < gameHalfCols) {
            for (float y = bottomLeft.dy; y < topRight.dy+1; y++) {
                if (y < gameHalfRows && y > -(gameHalfRows+1)) {
```

More importantly, the point of the first for loop is to start x at some minimum and increment it to some maximum, and the if statement is there to make sure x is at least some minimum and less than some maximum, so there's no reason to have both a for() and an if(). I don't know what the values might look like for topLeft.dx and gameHalfCols, so I can't tell you the best way to do this.

But, for example, if topLeft.dx is always integral, you might say:

```
    for (float x = MAX(topLeft.dx, ceil(-(gameHalfCols+1))); x < bottomRight.dx+1 && x < gameHalfCols; x++) {
        for (float y = ...
```

You could similarly improve the 'y' for this way. This sin't just fewer lines of code, it also prevents the loops from spinning a bunch of extra times with no effect: the 'if' statements just make the loops spin quickly to their ends, but including the logic inside the 'for's themselves makes them only loop over values that you'll actually use in computations.

Answer (score 0):

To expand my comments to a complete answer:

The normal, correct Objective-C behaviour when returning an object property is to `retain` and then `autorelease` it. That's because otherwise code like this (imagine you're in the world before ARC):

```
TYTemporaryWorker *object = [[TYTemporaryWorker alloc] initWithSomeValue:value];
NSNumber *someResult = object.someResult;
[object release];
return someResult;
```

would otherwise be invalid. `object` has been deallocated so if `someResult` hasn't been retained and autoreleased then it will become a dangling pointer. ARC makes this sort of slightly less direct (the strong reference in `someResult` would have retained the number beyond the lifetime of `object` but then it would have been autoreleased for the `return`) but the principle remains and, in any case, whether an individual .m file has been compiled with ARC is not supposed to affect callers.

(aside: notice that `weak` isn't just strong without retains — is has related costs because the runtime has to establish a link from the object to the weak reference in order to know find it again and `nil` it if the object begins deallocation)

Supposing you wanted to create a new type of property that isn't `strong` and isn't `unsafe_unretained` but is rather defined to be that the object returned is safe for use for as long as the original owner is alive but unsafe afterwards. So it's a `strong` set but an `unsafe_unretained` get.

It's untested but I think the correct means to do that would be:

```
// we can't write want a synthesised getter that doesn't attempt to retain
// or autorelease, so we'd better flag up the pointer as potentially being
// unsafe to access
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) NSNumber *someResult;

...

@implementation TYWhatever
{
    NSNumber *_retainedResult; // a strong reference, since
                               // I haven't said otherwise —
                               // this reference is not publicly exposed
}

- (void)setSomeResult:(NSNumber *)number
{
    // set the unsafe and unretained version,
    // as the default setter would have
    _someResult = number;

    // also take a strong reference to the object passed in,
    // to extend its lifecycle to match ours
    _retainedResult = number;
}
```

It's going to get quite verbose as you add more properties but what you're doing is contrary to normal Objective-C conventions so limited compiler help is probably to be expected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Hmm, I made the changes as you suggested, but there was no change in performance. For some reason, just adding the line CCUnit *tg = tower.target, and then looping so much, is increasing the sidetable items by an enormous amount. I don't really think it's about the setter, because I'm not setting anything a lot. I think it must be the getter?